# How to level up square signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a square signal +12V/-12V, 50kHz, with 0V as offset comming from a comparator (open collector), and I would like to change it into 0/+3.3V. I can change the comparator, but I can not change all others components. I tried this (we don't really care about the model of the op-amp):
R3 is mandatory (because of the open collector of my op-amp)
V1 is my +12V/-12V square voltage.

I try this circuit
[image]

Let's assume R1 = 10k. Voltage drop accross R1 is almost 0v.
Vdd = Ic*R1 + Vce => Ic = (Vdd-Vce)/R1 = (3.3-1)/10k = 2.3mA
We want the transitor be be saturated, so Ic <hfe*Ib, at worst case hfe= 30 So Ib > 76µA
(Vin-Vbe)/Ib = R4
To be sure that the transistor turn ON, vin should be higher than 2.5V
R4 = (2.5-0.75)/76µ = 23k

Are my calculation corrects?
How to find R3?

Thank you

The comparator is LM193:
https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/lm193.html
My transistor DP350T05-7:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DP350T05-7/989946Hello,

Comment: Not answering your question, so this is posted as a comment.  That circuit inverts the signal (which might be OK).  You can probably do what you want with a simple resistor divider such that when the opamp drives low (about -12V), the divider yields around 0V.  You can add a 3.3V logic gate after that as a buffer.  1G34, for example.

Comment: If the comparator is open collector why not just pull it up to 3.3v - you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Kevin's comment is the first thing I was wondering about. How in the heck do you have \$\pm 12\:\text{V}\$ if your (unshown, except as a signal generator symbol, I guess) comparator's output is open-collector?

Comment: Troutdog: Yes, it's not a problem to inverts the signal. I dislike the solution of the voltage divider, I want to try it with NPN/PNP by using power supply rail switch.
Kevin White, because my LM193 is supplied with +12V/-12V, so if I add pull it, I'll have 3.3V/-12V
Jonk: Because the LM193 is supplied with +12V/-12V.
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The following circuit will convert a +/- 12 volt square wave to a 0-3.3 volt square wave, assuming that the op-amp and the supply rails are chosen appropriately.

The calculated resistor values are unfortunately non-standard. If you keep the ratio between the resistors, you may vary their absolute values within reason. Changing the ratios slightly will change the outputs accordingly.

The resistor ratios were calculated as follows. Suppose all summing node is at 3.3V.  Then no current will flow through R1 and so the voltage divider composed of R2 and R3 must bring 12V down to 3.3V. R2 and R3 must therefore have the ratio of 29:11. Now, consider what happens when the input is 0V. The output needs to be 3.3/2=1.65V.  Since both the input side of R2 is at 0V and the ground side of R3 is at 0 volts, they can be modeled as a parallel resistor tied to 0 volts. R1 and that parallel resistor form a voltage divider that brings 3.3V to half that value, i.e. 1.65V. So R1 needs to be equal to the parallel value of R2 and R3. R1 = R2 || R3. I arbitrarily multiplied 11 and 29 by 4k to get 44k and 116k. That makes R1 have something approaching a whole number, i.e. 31.9k.

For newbies, the purpose of the op-amp is simply to avoid loading the voltage summing node. In the configuration it is in, the output voltage is almost exactly the input voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsMhhd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I'll keep your schematic. But I didn't understand what's wrong with my schematic. Could you explain it?

Comment: There is perhaps nothing wrong with your circuit. I apologize, but I didn't even try to make it work before I answered. I went with what seemed simplest to me (apart from the odd-ball resistor values, which to be honest, you probably don't care about the exact values). If there is a good reason for including the transistor (and there may be, I just don't know it) then I would be happy to see if I can calculate appropriate resistor values for that circuit.